# lazy loading, loader calling itself

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

With lazy loading, simple thing like

```
if(x==null) x = 10;
```

is more tricky.
Lets consider the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lzStrObj = new LzStrObj();
        lzStrObj.SetLzStrLoader(() => assignStr(lzStrObj));
        var result = lzStrObj.LzStr;
    }
    static string assignStr(LzStrObj lzStrObj)
    {
        if (lzStrObj.LzStr == null)
            return "newVal";
        return "freshVal";
    }
    class LzStrObj
    {
        private Lazy<string> _lzStr;
        public string LzStr => _lzStr?.Value;
        public void SetLzStrLoader(Func<string> ldr)
        {
            _lzStr = new Lazy<string>(ldr, LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the lazy loader `assignStr()` is performing the evaluation

```
if (lzStrObj.LzStr == null)
```

which triggers the lazy loading which in turn needs the loader which is just about to be defined so it is self circular. The example is dummy, it is an oversimplification of the real code. The real thing is much more complex and is very difficult to check that the loader, down the call chain, is not using the value about to be lazy loaded.

The question is how to avoid this?

Maybe something like: if a loader needs the lazy value, the previously defined loader should be used, if any, otherwise null. How a solution should look like?

Comment: Will checking for [`IsValueCreated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1.isvaluecreated?view=netcore-3.1) instead of null check help? Or what is the logic here?

Comment: @Guru Stron In time, during execution, the loader may be set more than once so checking IsValueCreated will work only at first.

Comment: TBH looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Can you describe a problem which you are trying to solve?

Comment: Also the simplified case does not actually make a lot of sense. In [`PublicationOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode?view=net-5.0#fields) mode the first thread to complete initialization sets the value, so if there is already some value set in the `lzStrObj.LzStr` it should not matter what you are returning in the init method cause it will be discarded.

Comment: Have you considered to use `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` with [that overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazyinitializer.ensureinitialized#System_Threading_LazyInitializer_EnsureInitialized__1___0__System_Boolean__System_Object__System_Func___0__) which receives the `ref bool initialized`